# Assign pointer contents to variable

Tags: c

Given a large `struct` pointer, say, `large_ptr`, and I want to assign it to a global var of the same type, let's call it `g_large`, then I have 2 options:

The first one using `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(&g_large, large_ptr, sizeof(g_large));
```

The second one using assignment:

```
g_large = *large_ptr;
```

Due to lack of memory and stack size in an embedded software I would like to know, does the second way behave like `memcpy`, or does it create a tmp var to do the assignment? Is there any standard for this?

If it behaves like `memcpy` then I'd prefer it for being shorter. But if it creates a temporary var, it might be a problem for the stack.

Your experience & knowledge will be appreciated!

### Edit

A few mentioned I need to compile and view the assembly.
This is a process I need to learn, since it's a cross compiler, which generates asm files that are binary and need to be parsed. Not a simple task. I could do that, but it will take time.

Comment: Compile your code with your compiler and see the assembly code to check.

Comment: `memcpy()` will do simple memory copy while `=` operator will use (potentially overloaded) `=` operator.

Comment: Why do you think a temporary variable will be needed?

Comment: @WeatherVane - I just occurred to me that it's a matter of implementation. If there's no standard way for it, then I'll need to take the safe path.

Comment: If they don't overlap (and single `struct`s shouldn't), all is well. If you copy a simple variable to another, it goes there directly.

Comment: Copying from A to B will not copy from A to tmp, then from tmp to B. Why do you even think it will?

Comment: `then I'll need to take the safe path` What's a safe path? Which path is dangerous? `does the second way behave like memcpy, or does it create a tmp var to do the assignment?` Compile the code and inspect the generated assembly. This depends on compilers options - usually I see `gcc -Os` calls `memcpy`, but `gcc -O3` generates walls of `mov`. Inspect the assembly to find out. `Is there any standard for this?` Standard for moving data from one place to another? No, just move them.

Comment: Uhm, assembly files are not binary, I think you mean object files. An assembly file is a text file. Anyway, each compiler I know can give you an output in assembly, and each assembler I know can give you a listing as text, and most compiler systems I know can generate a listing from an object file. (And I know a lot of compiler systems.) Just read the documentation.

Comment: @thebusybee yes, found it, it creates ELFs, and then there is elf dump..

Answer (score -1):

I may misunderstood but in ur memcpy function the sizeof(g_large) will always return 8 bytes as result since the size of a pointer in c is 8 bytes. Therefore you get the pointer size and not the struct size. It's like you can not find the size of an array if you only have the pointer addressing it.

[edit: oh yeah i misunderstood but anyway the following section is still recommended]

What I would do:

- dinamically allocate memory in main function
- pass the allocated memory pointer to the local function where you want to work with your struct
- extend the allocated memory if needed while working with your struct on the designated memory space
- at the end of the local function you will already have ur struct stored in main function memory space without any copy function needed

Comment: yeah realized just after posting :)

Comment: but considering ur lack of memory problem it would be recommended to allocate memory only in your global function and use it in ur local functionality. Since the way I explained you spare a copy method and also you spare a struct size memory block this way. The way you explained you will have a struct size memory in global and in local too. 'cors the local memory will be freed after the local function returns.

Comment: _sizeof(g_large) will always return 8 bytes_ why not 4 or 2 ? @rezoThePriest

Comment: @IrAM No, `sizeof g_large` **does not** always return 8, only on systems where the data type of `g_large` is 8 bytes. Other target systems have potentially other sizes.

Comment: @thebusybee, I am aware of that, just asking answerer so he can correct it because in the Q its not mentioned sizeof g_large  as 8 bytes